# Export to excel and pdf is not working after deploying .war file on Apache-tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat6, itext, apache-poi

Hii Guys !!
             I made a web application in which i have given two buttons to export data into .excel and .pdf format .I added following jar file  itext 2.1.0.jar,poi 2.5.1,poi scratchpad 3.0.1 -final   into my Libraries which i have saved into D:// drive of my local pc.

With these things in my library my application is running perfectly in netbeans .But after cleaning and building the project and deploying this .war file alone into tomcat exporting thing is not happening.

Plz guys help me out ....Any sugetions will heartely welcomed..

Answer (score 0):

those jars should be included in the war file also you should include them on your build script

Comment: will you plz tell me how to include those .jar files in the .war file

Comment: As an example `<path id="project.class.path">
     <pathelement location="war/WEB-INF/classes"/>
     <!-- Add any additional non-server libs (such as JUnit) -->
     <fileset dir="war/WEB-INF/lib" includes="**/*.jar"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Please double check there are itext and poi jars in your war. And paste your exception logs.

Answer (score 0):

As an example in reference to the comment

```
 <path id="project.class.path">
        <pathelement location="war/WEB-INF/classes"/>
        <!-- Add any additional non-server libs (such as JUnit) -->
        <fileset dir="war/WEB-INF/lib" includes="**/*.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="compile-lib-gwt" includes="**/*.jar"/>
<!--        <fileset dir="D:\Eclipse\eclipse-Jonu\plugins\com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.5.0.v201210291354-rel-r42\gwt-2.5.0" includes="**/*.jar"/> --> 
      </path>
```

and you put the JARs you want to add under WEB-INF/LIB

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your war deployment question, but it does answer the question you'll likely ask as soon as that's fixed....

You state that you're using two POI jars, `poi-2.5.1` and `poi-scratchpad-3.0.1-final`. Firstly, you shouldn't use mis-matched POI jars from different versions. You need to make sure you always use POI jars from the same release, eg `poi-3.8-final` + `poi-scratchpad-3.8-final` + `poi-ooxml-3.8-final`. The additional jars have dependencies on the core jar, and things won't work if they're mismatched.

Secondly, you're using POI 2.5.1, which was released on 2004-02-29, nearly 9 years ago! The list of bugs fixed then [is huge!](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html). You should upgrade to a version of POI from this decade at the very least.... And ideally the latest. That'll fix a lot of problems you've yet to hit